# Adding a single point with google API javascript v3 MarkerManager

Tags: javascript, api, markermanager

Hey all, I'm having problems on adding a single marker to a google map v3 using the marker manager. I understand that the manager is better suited for adding arrays, but I wish to understand how to add a single marker as part of the learning process. Can anyone point me in the correct direction? Here is the code I am currently working with to add a single marker:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.448903234142804, -98.51985454559326);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 10,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions); 

mgr = new MarkerManager(map);

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.448903234142804, -98.51985454559326);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng, 
  map: map, 
  title:"Hello World!"});
mgr.addMarker(marker,9,12);
mgr.refresh();}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you at the right zoom level to see the markers? Between 9 and 12.

Comment: I set the initialization to zoom 10, so it should show up right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were getting an error "google is not defined" place the link to markermanager.js e.g.  `<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/src/markermanager.js"></script>` within or after the BODY section of your HTML file.

========

Update: And now it works as you wish - tested!!

You have to do two things:
1st: load the MarkerManager source in the HEAD by:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/src/markermanager.js"><'+'/script>');
</script>
```

2nd: Tell manager to add your marker after the map is loaded:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function(){
mgr.addMarker(marker,9,12);
mgr.refresh();});
}
```

Good luck

K

Comment: So it works for me fine the way you did it. Have a look at the test page which includes also adding of one marker with markermanager http://wichry.net/page/testa.html. BTW. marker is somewhere in Belgium.

Comment: Well, the tester page works fine for me, and I am able to see the marker if I take out all of the code i have pertaining to the marker manager. I still havent had any luck, I added the library (as I was told to?) and still no luck.

Comment: when I add `<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/src/markermanager.js"></script>` after the </body> it works nicely for me. Have a look at http://wichry.net/page/testb.html.

Comment: Alright, I added it after the </body> but now it shows up at all zoom levels, it does not appear to be limited by the zoom levels i have set?

Comment: Hey you did indeed answer the first question, but now another problem has arisen. If I have the marker in the window for initialization, it is always placed on the map no matter what the zoom level is. If i go within the range I set with the marker manager, and then leave it however, the marker will disappear.

Comment: I solved this secondary problem through my own determination! Haha! if you look at the "var" called "marker" in my code, I included the attribute "map:", however, the markermanager seems to handle that attribute on its own; therefore, I removed the "map:" attribute, and now second problem is solved!

Comment: That is true. I did not test the intialization of the map out of the zoom range for the marker. Interestingly, if you let say init at zoom 8 and your marker has range (9,12) then if you zoom into the range and then out of it - marker dissapears. Anyway, good you found the final solution.